# Adjust code by changing function eregi_replace

Tags: php, regex

How can I adjust my code by replacing the "eregi_replace" function with another one that does the same thing?

I know the alternatives, but I do not know how to update the code. O erro que recebo é:

**PHP Deprecated: Function eregi_replace**

```
function url($String){

    $Separador = "-";

    $String = trim($String);
    $String = strtolower($String);
    $String = strip_tags($String);
    $String = eregi_replace("[[:space:]]", $Separador, $String); 

    $String = eregi_replace("[çÇ]", "c", $String);
    $String = eregi_replace("[áÁäÄàÀãÃâÂ]", "a", $String);
    $String = eregi_replace("[éÉëËèÈêÊ]", "e", $String);
    $String = eregi_replace("[íÍïÏìÌîÎ]", "i", $String);
    $String = eregi_replace("[óÓöÖòÒõÕôÔ]", "o", $String);
    $String = eregi_replace("[úÚüÜùÙûÛ]", "u", $String);

    $String = eregi_replace("(\()|(\))", $Separador, $String);
    $String = eregi_replace("(\/)|(\\\)", $Separador, $String);
    $String = eregi_replace("(\[)|(\])", $Separador, $String);
    $String = eregi_replace("[@®#\$%&\*\+=\|º]", $Separador, $String);
    $String = eregi_replace("[;:'\"<>,\.?!_]", $Separador, $String);
    $String = eregi_replace("[“”]", $Separador, $String);
    $String = eregi_replace("(ª)+", $Separador, $String);
    $String = eregi_replace("[´~^°]", $Separador, $String);

    $String = eregi_replace("($Separador)+", $Separador, $String);
    $String = substr($String, 0, 100);
    $String = eregi_replace("(^($Separador)+)|(($Separador)+$)", "", $String);
    $String = str_replace("-", $Separador, $String);

    return $String;
}
```

Comment: What is the problem you have when you replace the `eregi_replace()` function with the alternatives?

Comment: I'm not aware, I've tried using the following alternatives: http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pcre.php. I do not know which one is correct, but I just replace the word `eregi_replace` with the alternative, and none worked.

Comment: The PHP docs point to `preg_replace` using the `i` modifier for case insensitivity.  A quick check of the docs - http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php - makes it seem like you just need to replace your `eregi_replace` with `preg_replace`.

Comment: PHP Warning:  preg_replace(): Compilation failed: POSIX named classes are supported only within a class at offset 0 in

Comment: You need delimiters in all patterns, try `/` as `$String = preg_replace("/[[:space:]]/i", $Separador, $String);`. Obviously you won't need the `i` in all patterns since spaces etc. don't have case.

Comment: And actually you're converting them to lowercase with `strtolower()` and have the upper and lower in the pattern as well, so probably don't need it at all ;-)

Comment: That code is ridiculous...  If you actually know what it's doing, what a waste of space.